# Show Small Icon in notification Bar but hide in notification Panel

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I try to find this one in this forum and I found a couple but no one worked for me. I just need to hide it in the notification panel where appears next to the large icon but if I hide it, it also dissapears from the notification bar.

[image]

Is there any way to show only the large icon as is happening in the first and fourth notifications?
This is the code that I am using:

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent;

    Notification.Builder mBuilder =
            new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.small_icon).setTicker(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                    .setLights(Color.GREEN, 1000, 1000)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(extras.getString("message")))
                    .setContentText(extras.getString("message"));
        edit.putString(Config.FRAGMENT, extras.getString("fragment"));
        edit.commit();
        intent = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                intent, 0);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working for me.

try it

```
Notification.Builder builder=new Notification.Builder(this);
            builder.setContentIntent(intent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification).setTicker(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(message);
            Notification notification = builder.build();
```

Comment: But what about the large icon? I need to have different icons in the header and in the notification list.

Comment: If you want to set large Icon then you can not hide small icon. In above screen shots You show single icon If you not set largeIcon. You can change  color. using `builder.setColor(<colorCode>)`

Answer (score 7):

You can make it invisible after building the notification :

```
int smallIconId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("right_icon", "id", android.R.class.getPackage().getName());
            if (smallIconId != 0) {
                notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconId, View.INVISIBLE);
                notification.bigContentView.setViewVisibility(smallIconId, View.INVISIBLE);
            }
```

Comment: Hi, is this still safe? contentView and bigContentView is deprecated.

Comment: apparently, it should be replaced with [setCustomBigContentView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setCustomBigContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews)), I'll update the answer for api 24+

Comment: not works for builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)